# How to implement text search in a deskop app?

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, electron, desktop-application

I plan to distribute tens of thousands of HTML files with my desktop application.  I need a way to provide an efficient search so that user can find a desired file based on keyword. Ideally, this would work similar to a google search that would permit some of the operators to be used in a search. 
What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your thousands of files are static and local, so ideally you would pre-index them and provide the index as part of your bundle.

I have not tried myself (I'm interested by the idea for a similar feature), but I see [lunr.js](https://lunrjs.com) offers this possibility: ["index prebuilding"](https://lunrjs.com/guides/index_prebuilding.html). License is MIT.